# How to check that a GLSL shader is under native limits?

Tags: opengl, glsl

For `GL_ARB_fragment_program` and `GL_ARB_vertex_program` there's a query like `GL_PROGRAM_UNDER_NATIVE_LIMITS_ARB`. If the result of the query is `GL_FALSE`, then the program will most likely be executed in software.

Is there any way to query this for a GLSL shader or program object?

Comment: Why do you need to query it for an individual shader?

Comment: @t.niese so that I can replace it with a simpler one, or fallback to something not requiring a shader at all, etc.. It'd be OK to query on the level of complete linked program object, of course, too, not necessarily individual _shader_.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query you can perform to test for something like that. If a shader cannot be executed on the hardware, for reasons other than the standard provides (using more uniforms than allowed, etc), then the implementation has two options. It can either execute it in hardware or simply fail to compile/link the shader and provide a message explaining why.